# Restarting counter on click or disabling it - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this JavaScript function which counts down until you can click the download button, however i would like once its clicked for it either to disable again or start counting down again, preferably, disable.

Here is the JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  x = 10;
  function countdown() {
    if (x > 1) {
      x--;
      document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = x;
      r = setTimeout("countdown()",1000);
    }
    else {
      clearTimeout(r);
      document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "Click to download";
      document.getElementById("button").disabled = "";
    }
  }
  r = setTimeout("countdown()",1000);

</script>
```

Here is the button,

```
<label><font size="5">Your download will start in: </label><a href="download.php?shortURL=<?php echo $fullfile; ?>"><button class="btn orange" id="button" disabled="disabled" onclick="window.location.reload()" >10</button></font></a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just a note, your HTML is malformed - The `<font>` tag must be closed before the `<label>` tag is closed.

Comment: No problems, i just want when you click the button, for the counter to  start again

Comment: Is gifting answers common-place in the javascript tag? OP made no attempt at understanding the problem. He simply stated the expected behavior, barfed a generic countdown function and was happily greeted with more than one complete-solution. The selected answer doesn't even explain what's going on. Is that the quality that can be expected of Javascript? People pay money for this kind of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the code you need:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var x = 10;
        var r = 0;
        function countdown() {
            if (x > 1) {
                x--;
                document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = x;
                r = setTimeout("countdown()",1000);
            }
            else {
                clearTimeout(r);
                document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "Click to download";
                document.getElementById("button").disabled = "";
                document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
                    document.getElementById("button").disabled = "disabled";
                };

            }
        }
        setTimeout("countdown()",1000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<label>
    <font size="5">Your download will start in:</font>
</label>
<a href="download.php?shortURL=<?php echo $fullfile; ?>" target="_blank">
    <button class="btn orange" id="button" disabled="disabled">10</button>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes this worked great, one more thing, how can i get it to say, on the button "Download will start in: "10", but only the number change?

Answer (score 3):

To start the countdown again, you can just create a function to clear any existing timer and reset your counter variable and then call this function from the `onclick` event of your button:

```
function resetCountdown() {
    clearTimeout(r);
    x = 10;
    countdown();
}
```

To disable the button, you can set it to disabled:

```
document.getElementById("button").disabled = "disabled";
```

Answer (score 1):

First why u r using window.location.reload() ?.. it is something related to your script ? if not than remove it and try the below jquery code

```
        $(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $(this).attr("disabled",true);
    });
```

and make sure to include a copy of jquery to make it work or include the below link in your head tag before this script

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why you posted a link to the 1.3.2 version of jQuery? :))

Comment: hey cristy .. it is not a hardcore script and can even work with version 1 , i was having this link in one my file so just copied from there ... n you r free to 1.7.1  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but try this. It will disable the button once its clicked after "Click to download" is displayed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 x = 10;
 function countdown() {
    if (x > 1) {
       x--;
       document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = x;
       r = setTimeout("countdown", 1000);
    } else {
       clearTimeout(r);
       document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "Click to download";
       document.getElementById("button").disabled = "";
       document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
          document.getElementById("button").disabled = "disabled";
       };
    }
 }
 r = setTimeout("countdown",1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var x = 10;
var r = setInterval(
  function() {
    if (x > 1) {
      x--;
      document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = x;
    }
    else {
      clearInterval(r);
      document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "Click to download";
      document.getElementById("button").disabled = "";
    }
}, 1000);
```